# Angular can not render generated HTML with Button dynamically

Tags: angular, button, render, innerhtml

I am facing a problem, I want to render generated HTML code, into material table with Pipe, but it is not working.

the code looks like this:

pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import * as _ from "underscore";

@Pipe({ name: "customPipeChecks" })
export class CustomPipeChecks implements PipeTransform {
  transform(
    elementValue: {},
    elementProperty: string,
    object: {},
    customPipeFunction: any,
    defaultValue: string
  ) {
    if (customPipeFunction != null && _.isFunction(customPipeFunction)) {
      console.log(customPipeFunction(elementValue, elementProperty, object));
      return customPipeFunction(elementValue, elementProperty, object);
    } else {
      if (defaultValue) {
        return defaultValue;
      }
      return elementValue;
    }
  }
}
```

the generated function

```
  private setCustomValueFunction() {
    this.customValueFunction = (
      elemValue: string,
      elemKey: string,
      elem: {}
    ) => {
      if (elemKey === "vin") {
        elemValue = "<button>zrdzdrz</button>";
      }
      return elemValue;
    };
  }
```

this function generates a HTML string.

the HTML code looks like this :

```
<td
     mat-cell
     *matCellDef="let cellData"
     class="{{
              cellData[colName]
                | customPipeChecks: colName:cellData:customCssFunction:' '
            }}"
     innerHtml="{{
              cellData[colName]
                | customPipeChecks: colName:cellData:customValueFunction
       }}">
</td>
```

When the app is loaded, it will shown only 'zrdzdrz' only the text (inner HTML of the desired button), without the button (that is suppoused to wrap the text).

Any suggestion?

Best Regards,

Leo

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting question.

Here is a demo at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/inject-html-example) that will fix your problem.

The reason why your implementation doesn't work is because angular is sanitizing the injected HTMl, in order to bypass this, your custom pipe should look like the snippet bellow, where the important part is the usage of `DomSanitizer` which will "tell" the framework in explicit manner that you want to inject `HTML` that must be rendered.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import {
  DomSanitizer,
  SafeHtml
} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: "customPipeChecks" })
export class CustomPipeChecks implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(
    public sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
  ) { }
  transform() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<button>Button content</button>')
  }
}
```

## Update

One more notable point is that in the template you must inject the `innerHTML` in the following manner,  **[innerHTML]**

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [innerHtml]="'someString' | customPipeChecks">
    </td>
```

Comment: Hi I have tried your solution, but I become this error: SafeValue must use [property]=binding: 12 (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)

Comment: Hi, Thx for your solution, I have also a qustion, I want to add a click funciton in this button, where should I implement this button click function? Maybe you can give more information.

Comment: If I was in your shoes I would've go for another solution , instead of pipe that would inject HTML, I would go for a new component that will have some `*ngIf` logic based on inputs, by doing so you will have much better control over the behavior of the cell content and would be able easily to catch all kind of events, (like click, hover etc) and respond to them. 
If you are not able to go with the first strategy I suggested, you can always query the dom and add event listeners to the added button.
p.s. go for the first strategy (the one with the component) if possible

Comment: Hi have also a question, if you want to add a click function into button and when the button clicked and called this function, how should it implement?

Comment: You can catch the click button event `<button (click)="clickHandler($event)"></button>` check out this part of the tour of heroes tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2 , also i would recomend you to complete the whole tutorial.

Comment: I have implemented this way, but it was not working.